# How can I get a consistent colouring scheme in ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

I am creating nice plots doing something like this:

[image: Mathematica code snapshot]

However, in some cases some classes are not present. So eg if class 1 is missing in data2 , then the colour of the other classes are shifted by one colour. How can I fix this?

Here's the code that could be copied to reproduce this:

```
data1 = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 5}],
  RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2, 3}]}, 100];
data2 = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 5}],
  RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}]}, 100];

mylegend = 
  PointLegend[{
   RGBColor[0.237736, 0.340215, 0.575113],
   RGBColor[0.277947,0.45009699999999997`,0.32815550000000004`],
   RGBColor[0.72987, 0.239399, 0.230961],
   RGBColor[0.8562609999999999, 0.742794, 0.31908333333333333`]},
  {"Class 0", "Class 1", "Class 2", "Class 3"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20]; 

ListDensityPlot[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotLegends -> mylegend,
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", FrameLabel -> {x, y},
  LabelStyle -> Large, RotateLabel -> False]
```

For data 1 the result will look something like this:
[image: data 1 listdensityplot]

And data 2 will look something like this:

[image: data 2 listdensityplot]

Even though the data 2 has been generated explicitly without data that belongs to class 0, there's a lot of blue, because of class 1 data taking the class 0 colour, etc.

Comment: Post code not screenshots. Copy and paste code into a block ``` ``` Also post a minimum amount of data necessary to reproduce the problem (give some of data1 / data2)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, I've edited the question to clarify better and include code that can be copied to reproduce the problem. I had avoided that because Mathematica code usually becomes unreadable when copied somewhere else, but I hope this helps!

Comment: `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#/3] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! Downside is of course, that one has to check the data for missing classes every time before plotting, I'm sure there has to be a way to assign fixed colours to the classes. But this works for me, thanks!

Comment: I think what I suggested works whether classes are missing or not, so you don't have to check each time. However, it assumes that the classes are numbered 0,1,2,3. For classes numbered a,a+1,...,b, you need to change the rescaling `#/3` to `(#-a)/(b-a)`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 you are right it works perfectly, thank you! I've read up on the Mathematica slot operator, but tbh I still don't quite get what the "[#/3] &" means... Could you perhaps give a short explanation on what this does?

Comment: `#` stands for the first argument (passed to the color function in this case). You have to read the `ListDensityPlot` docs to find out how it uses color function: It passes just one argument, the scaled (or unscaled, if `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`) 3rd coordinate of the data. In your case, the 3rd coord is 0,1,2, or 3. So `#/3` will be 0, 1/3, 2/3, or 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flexible approach is to make your list of colors and map classes to colors as follows:

```
classes = {0, 1, 2, 3};
mycolorlist = ColorData["DarkRainbow"] /@ Rescale[classes];

ListDensityPlot[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 PlotLegends -> mylegend, 
 ColorFunction -> (mycolorlist[[1 + #]] &), (* assumes values are integers *)
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> Large, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can also use the form `ColorData[{"gradient", {min, max}}]` to get a color gradient that ranges from `min` to `max` to define a custom color function:

```
ClearAll[commonColorFunction, commonLegend]

commonColorFunction[datasets_List, colorscheme_: "DarkRainbow"] := 
  ColorData[{colorscheme, MinMax @ Flatten[#[[All, -1]] & /@ datasets]}];

commonLegend[datasets_List, colorscheme_: "DarkRainbow"] := 
  Module[{vals = Union @ Flatten[#[[All, -1]] & /@ datasets]}, 
   PointLegend[commonColorFunction[datasets, colorscheme] /@ vals, 
    "Class " <> ToString[#] & /@ vals, LegendMarkerSize -> 20]];
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]

dataa = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 5}], 
    RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2, 3}]}, 100];

datab = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 5}], 
    RandomChoice[{1, 2, 4}]}, 100];


ListDensityPlot[dataa, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> commonColorFunction[{dataa, datab}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> commonLegend[{dataa, datab}],
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> Large, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[datab, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> commonColorFunction[{dataa, datab}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> commonLegend[{dataa, datab}], 
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> Large, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]